# javascript: random generator with the combination of number and text without repetition

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

My use case is to create a random generator with the combination of letters **A to Z** and numbers **from 0 to 9** the generated output should be in the length of 10 main scenario is there should not be any repetition.

Comment: nice. what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomString(){
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var text="";
            for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

                var c=possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
                if(text!="" && text[text.length-1]==c){
                    i--;
                }else{
                    text+=c;
                }
            }
            return text;
        }
```